# PayPal Standard Payment On Hold or Pending

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am using `PayPal` standard to make transactions in a WordPress website. I've set the API credentials and works perfectly means the transactions are done perfectly. But when I open the SandBox buyer account, I can see the following with pending status and the payments don't appear in the seller's account:

[image: PayPal Standard]

I've seen the `PayPal` official site to check this out and they say, sometimes they put on hold for verification. I would like to know if anyone has faced it before and how will this be available or completed later?

I've one another thing to know - I've used the **PayPal Express Checkout** plugin for transactions. But in the dashboard, it says **WooCommerce Gateway PayPal Express Checkout requires OpenSSL >= 1.0.1 to be installed on your server** and doesn't show the feature in the `WooCommerce` checkout settings. So do I have to set SSL for that?

**Note**: I am doing the above in localhost using **WAMP**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use localhost it's not a valid URL, PayPal can't access your local enviornment.Local host cannot be resolved on distant machines in case Paypal server.

Best way upload  to the web, there's a number of free PHP web hosts out there if you don't have one.

Comment: So you mean for using localhost, this is happening @Vasim Vanzara? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: yes,I mean you have to host on server.It will resolve.

Comment: OK - I'll do so @Vasim Vanzara. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok let me know if any other issue.

Comment: It worked and I've used the **PayPal Standard** for the payment gateway @Vasim Vanzara. Just a quick question, I've used the **WooCommerce Express Checkout** earlier with free hosting and just willing to know if it requires SSL certificate as it says in the dashboard - **Requires OpenSSL > 1.0.1 to be installed on your server**. Is it mandatory?

Comment: its depend on plugin configuration.